# onClick method in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So what I have is two components - one is *MainComponent* and the other is *MenuComponent* written in ReactJS

The *MenuComponent* is imported into the MainComponent

The *MainComponent* is as shown below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes';

class Main extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            dishes: DISHES,
            selectedDish: null
        }
    }
    onDishSelect(dishId){
        this.setState({selectedDish: dishId})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="App">
                <Navbar dark color="primary">
                    <div className="container">
                        <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
                    </div>
                </Navbar>
                <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId)=>this.onDishSelect(dishId)}/>
                <DishDetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish)=>dish.id===this.state.selectedDish)[0]}/>
            </div>            
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

The render method of MenuComponent is as shown below:

```
render(){
    const menu=this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
        return(
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <Card key={dish.id}
                    onClick={() => this.props.onClick(dish.id)}>
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardImgOverlay>
                        <CardTitle><h5 className='font'>{dish.name}</h5></CardTitle>
                    </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>                    
            </div>
        );
    });
```

I'm totally new to React, so I would like to know how the *onClick* event handler defined in MenuComponent works:

- So when a card is clicked (in *MenuComponent*), is the *this.props.onClick* invoked? Why
  is *this.props* used here?
- The same *onClick* method is used in the MainComponent, with a *dishId*
  (from where?) passed as parameter, I'm kind of confused on how this
  all *onClick* event is processed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using this.props to update the state in the parent component. Without using this.props, there is no way to update state in the parent component with your child component. This is how you update state with a child component.

When you import a component into another component, that imported component becomes that components child.

Yes when a card is clicked, it invokes the onClick prop you have created.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.
The `dish.id` is passed to `props.onClick` when click occurs on a card. and
`props.onClick` is `onDishSelect` actually, when called with an argument, it will set parent component's `state.selectedDish` equal to that argument(in this case child's dish id)

Comment: So is the MenuComponent the MainComponent's child? How is that relation defined?

Comment: it's being rendered in `MainComponent`: `<Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId)=>this.onDishSelect(dishId)}/>`. so we call it a child of `MainComponent`

Answer (score 0):

Here You are passing onClick method as props to Menu component with argument

```
<Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} onClick={(dishId)=>this.onDishSelect(dishId)}/>
```

Here you are calling that onClick props inside Menu component when card is being clicked passing dishId as argument

```
<Card key={dish.id}
                onClick={() => this.props.onClick(dish.id)}>
                <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                <CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardTitle><h5 className='font'>{dish.name}</h5></CardTitle>
                </CardImgOverlay>
            </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking on the `<Card>` element, this fires the `onClick` function that is received by `MenuComponent` via props. So basically `this.props` is an object representing props passed to the component and from that object you're extracting your `onClick` which in case of implementation of this component in `MainComponent` is your `onDishSelect` method.

You could as well invoke the `MenuComponent` in different context, and could pass different function as the `onClick` prop.

```
const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
  const logHelloOnClick = () => {
     console.log('hello');
  }

  return (
    <MenuComponent onClick={logHelloOnClick}/>
  )
}
```

In this case when you clicked on the `Card`, "hello" msg would be logged to the console.

Therefore try to realize that props passed to a component are basically the same as arguments passed to any other function.

```
const logTestToConsole = text => {
  console.log(text)
};

const functionMimickingComponent = props => {
  const taskToRun = props.tastToRun;
  taskToRun('hello');
};

functionMimickingComponent({ taskToRun: logTestToConsole }); // this logs "hello" to the console
```